# Vue router push is push back to the same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, page-refresh, onbeforeunload

Im really newbie to the Vue, so i try to handle beforeunload event so that if user refresh the page i will rediect from "/game" page to "/lobby" page,

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',  (event) => {
  this.$router.push("lobby")
})
```

but when it push to "/lobby" some how it still remain at "/game"

Comment: hey there, use vue router instead of adding event listener on window. see this https://router.vuejs.org/

Comment: You could maybe try the following `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', async (event) => { await this.$router.push("/lobby") })` but overall, using a middleware or a vue-router guard is indeed more adapted.